# $f(n) = \int_{1}^{n} n^{x^{-1}}dx$. $\frac{df}{dn}$?

Tags: integration, recreational-mathematics, radicals

Lets start with the domain $1 \leq n \in \mathbb{R}$:

$f(n) = \int_{1}^{n} n^{x^{-1}}dx$

$\frac{df}{dn}$ should be sort of logarithmic and probably not interesting.?

What is it, though?

What have I tried?
To see how far it is from something interesting, and maybe more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:  EVALUATION OF $\displaystyle f(n)$ AND DIRECT DIFFERENTIAION**

**EVALUTING $\displaystyle f(n)$:**

We can write the integral of interest in terms of the Exponential Integral $\text{Ei}(x)$.

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
f(n)&=\int_1^n n^{1/x}\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=\int_{1/n}^1 \frac{n^x}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{1/n}^1 \frac{e^{\log(n)x}}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\log(n)\int_{\log(n)/n}^{\log(n)} \frac{e^x}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\log(n)\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)+n(n^{1/n}-1)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

---

**DIFFERENTIATING $\displaystyle f(n)$:**

To determine $f'(n)$ we begin with $(2)$ and write

$$\begin{align}
f'(n)&=\frac1n\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)\\\\
&+\log(n)\left(\frac{1}{\log(n)}-\frac{n}{\log(n)}\frac{dn^{1/n}}{dn}\right)\\\\
&+(n^{1/n}-1)+n\frac{dn^{1/n}}{dx}\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)\tag 3
\end{align}$$

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:  APPLYING LEIBNIZ'S RULE**

Using Leibniz's Rule, we differentiate $(1)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
f'(n)&=n^{1/n}+\int_1^n \frac{n^{1/x-1}}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{n^x}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n \int_{\log(n)/n}^{\log(n)}\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the result reported in $(3)$!

Comment: I used the Leibniz Rule, took $n^{-1}$ out, used $g'(x) = log'(x)=x^{-1}$ and $h(x)=n^{x^{-1}}$ and rewrote by parts, substitution made it almost trivial looking from there on and this sprung the mistake in getting the pre-school antiderivative right (sensed the mistake, now I see it) but still toyed around with the final nice expression. Tried to look if I got it right using Sage that did it much faster and then several $Ei$ looked at me. At the time (a week ago) I felt I didn't need another Euler to deal with. Now I do though. :)

Comment: Question: Is there a "closed form" expression for this, like my nice mistake was?

Comment: (This is just question #1)

Comment: @Dror This is as nice a closed-form as one can get.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark