# Can you find $f(n) = \int_{1}^{n} n^{x^{-1}}dx$. $\frac{df}{dn}$ using Leibniz rule of differentiation under integration$?

Tags: integration

The domain $1 \leq n \in \mathbb{R}$:

$f(n) = \int_{1}^{n} n^{x^{-1}}dx$

[$f(n) = \int_{1}^{n} n^{x^{-1}}dx$. $\frac{df}{dn}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242396/fn-int-1n-nx-1dx-fracdfdn) this is the original question which was asked a week before here, and I couldn't solve it, but since no one answered it yet, I am asking this question again.

Comment: Did you use the general form of Leibniz rule?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign which includes the partial fraction as well

Comment: ^Yes I do @LakshyaGupta  But still I am not solve it.

Comment: In which terms is the answer expressed in?

Comment: @LakshyaGupta I don't know since the OP didn't uploaded the answer and as I told you it's not mine, someone else asked it on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:  EVALUATION OF $\displaystyle f(n)$ AND DIRECT DIFFERENTIAION**

**EVALUTING $\displaystyle f(n)$:**

We can write the integral of interest in terms of the Exponential Integral $\text{Ei}(x)$.

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
f(n)&=\int_1^n n^{1/x}\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=\int_{1/n}^1 \frac{n^x}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{1/n}^1 \frac{e^{\log(n)x}}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\log(n)\int_{\log(n)/n}^{\log(n)} \frac{e^x}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\log(n)\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)+n(n^{1/n}-1)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

---

**DIFFERENTIATING $\displaystyle f(n)$:**

To determine $f'(n)$ we begin with $(2)$ and write

$$\begin{align}
f'(n)&=\frac1n\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)\\\\
&+\log(n)\left(\frac{1}{\log(n)}-\frac{n}{\log(n)}\frac{dn^{1/n}}{dn}\right)\\\\
&+(n^{1/n}-1)+n\frac{dn^{1/n}}{dx}\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)\tag 3
\end{align}$$

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:  APPLYING LEIBNIZ'S RULE**

Using Leibniz's Rule, we differentiate $(1)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
f'(n)&=n^{1/n}+\int_1^n \frac{n^{1/x-1}}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{n^x}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n \int_{\log(n)/n}^{\log(n)}\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=n^{1/n}+\frac1n\left(\text{Ei}(\log(n))-\text{Ei}(\log(n^{1/n}))\right)
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the result reported in $(3)$!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark